# Encrypt gRPC communication with TLS and with Nginx ingress (migrating from REST)

Tags: go, kubernetes, nginx, ssl, nginx-ingress

I'm currently exploring gRPC as an alternative to REST to do client/server communication.

At the moment, I have a Dart/flutter application (my client) running mostly on mobiles. It communicates with a Go backend (my server) with REST.
The backend is deployed on a Kubernetes cluster. There is a Nginx ingress controller sitting in front of the backend. I have an Ingress rule that does this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: fancy-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port:
              number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fancy-domain.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod-tls
```

With this kind of setup, on the client can simply use any classic HTTP client, and I know that the client will take care of fetching the certificate from `fancy-domain.com` to encrypt the traffic. Since this certificate is signed by a trusted 3rd party (let's encrypt in this case), the client also knows for sure it's talking to the right domain.

When it comes to migrating to gRPC, I'm struggling to see how this would work. All the guides I found online show the client using certificates somewhat embedded on the client's side (they directly load `*.pem` files). But it looks like they're talking directly to the backend.

What I *think* I want to do is to make the client use the certificate provided by my domain (the client should fetch them it the domain, not have the certificate somehow embedded somewhere), and I would like the TLS termination done at the ingress controller level.

Is it possible? I couldn't find any documentation about such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out the code above (for the ingress rule) was almost ready. I just added this annotation:

```yaml
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: 'GRPC'
```

And then on the client side, it's as simple as doing this:

```dart
    final channel = ClientChannel(
      'fancy-domain.com',
      port: 443,
      options: ChannelOptions(
        credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(),
        codecRegistry:
            CodecRegistry(codecs: const [GzipCodec(), IdentityCodec()]),
      ),
    );
    var client = YourApiClient(channel);
```

Everything just works out of the box.